# Django and embeding videos using parsing to get the youtube video id

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I feel like i am very close to making it work. i tired everything but the videos don't show. the problem is in the HTML i think.

## Models:

```
  class Video(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()

    def video_id(link):

        query = urlparse(link)
        if query.hostname == 'youtu.be':
            return query.path[1:]
        if query.hostname in ('www.youtube.com', 'youtube.com'):
            if query.path == '/watch':
                p = parse_qs(query.query)
                return p['v'][0]
            if query.path[:7] == '/embed/':
                return query.path.split('/')[2]
            if query.path[:3] == '/v/':
                return query.path.split('/')[2]




    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.link
```

## views:

```
def index(request):
full_list = Video.objects.all()
return render_to_response('index.html', {'full_list': full_list})
```

## HTML:

```
{%load staticfiles %}
{%load static%}
<h1>YouTube list</h1>
{% if full_list %}
  <ul>
     {% for video in full_list %}
       <li>


  <iframe width="560" height="345" src="{{Video.video_id}}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </li>

{% endfor %}
 </ul>
{% endif %}
```

i have been at it for three days now and i can't seem to make the videos appear.

Comment: In a class method the first argument should be called `self` and will become the instance you call it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have created a function inside the `Video` class, you are not passing the "self" as the first argument. Also, you are trying to access it as a property instead of a function on the template.

The fixed code should be something like this:

```
#  Model:
class Video(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()

    @property
    def video_id(self):
        query = urlparse(self.link)
        if query.hostname == 'youtu.be':
            return query.path[1:]
        if query.hostname in ('www.youtube.com', 'youtube.com'):
            if query.path == '/watch':
                p = parse_qs(query.query)
                return p['v'][0]
            if query.path[:7] == '/embed/':
                return query.path.split('/')[2]
            if query.path[:3] == '/v/':
                return query.path.split('/')[2]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.link
```

Then later on the template, use it the same as you would on a property:

```
<iframe width="560" height="345" src="{{Video.video_id}}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Otherwise, you could make it a function:

```
#  Model:
class Video(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()

    def video_id(self):
        query = urlparse(self.link)
        if query.hostname == 'youtu.be':
            return query.path[1:]
        if query.hostname in ('www.youtube.com', 'youtube.com'):
            if query.path == '/watch':
                p = parse_qs(query.query)
                return p['v'][0]
            if query.path[:7] == '/embed/':
                return query.path.split('/')[2]
            if query.path[:3] == '/v/':
                return query.path.split('/')[2]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.link
```

But then you would need to call it as a function:

```
<iframe width="560" height="345" src="{{Video.video_id()}}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Ok how do i call it in the html then? also thank you.

Comment: Remove the `@property`, then you should be able to call it on the template function using `src="{{Video.video_id()}}?rel=0"`.

Comment: tried it but it gave me this error:  

Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'Video.video_id()'

Comment: Updated the code to include the both ways of using it. Remember to restart the server after the modifications on the code

Comment: The code is working but the videos still aren't appearing. i even removed the for loop and just opted to show just one video and it didn't work still.

Comment: Try adding `https://www.youtube.com/embed/` before the {{Video.video_id}}, eg: `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{Video.video_id()}}?rel=0"`. Also, don't forget to upvote & mark as correct if everything worked

Comment: Its still not working. i am at my wits end honestly. :( the embed video shows but when you press play the video. the player says an error occurred. and if it works i ll donate to you my kidney.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Just tested your code with some dummy data.

Comment: thanks bud for your help. i am gonna tear it down and build it up again. i might have made a silly mistake here or there.